# Windows command line not executing multiple commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, visual-studio-2017, cpputest

I am building a visual studio project through command line for that I need to run multiple commands at once.So I am created a batch file which includes all the commands.When I run the batch file only first command is executed.My batch file is given below

test.bat

```
C:
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build 
vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
devenv D:\Jenkins\cpputest-master\cpputest-master\CppUTest.sln /Build
D:
cd D:\Jenkins\cpputest-master\cpputest-master\cpputest_build
mv AllTests.exe D:\Jenkins\jenkinsHome\workspace\TestCppUTest
cd D:\Jenkins\jenkinsHome\workspace\TestCppUTest
AllTests.exe -ojunit
```

When I run this batch file first three commands are executed,fourth command is not executed.But if I run these commands using && all the commands are executed.Any suggestions??

Comment: Instead of `D:` and `cd D:\...` you could just use `cd /D D:\...`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call a batch file from within a batch file, you need to use `call` otherwise your calling batch file will be terminated.

So instead of

```
vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
```

you need to use:

```
call vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
```

If `devenv` is also a batch file, then it needs to be replaced with `call devenv` as well.

Comment: ya it's worked.But the last command is not executed ,how to call an  .exe file??

Comment: You don't need to do anything special for exe files

Comment: Is there anything for move command?

Comment: Is `mv`  a batch file?

Comment: No.It is a command for move an .exe file to another location.

Comment: Move command working fine .After the move command command line stopps the execution.All other commands are not executed.

Comment: Then it's a problem with that `mv` thing.

Comment: Yes.It's a problem about `mv` .

Comment: I got the answer.I am changed `mv` to `move` now it's working fine and executed all the commands.